# datetimepicker jQuery are affecting two different inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to set date formats in two different inputs using they ids but both are recognizing the same format.

Html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="validity" asp-for="@Model.Validity" value="" />
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="deadline" asp-for="@Model.Deadline" value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#validity').datepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        dateFormat: 'd M',
        minDate: '0'
    });

    $('#deadline').datepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: '0'
    });
```

The the last dateformat ($('#deadline').datepicker) is affecting both inputs and the first dateformt is ignoring.

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Input value is coming proper format @EduardoAngelim

Answer (score 0):

Try using `format` option instead of `dateFormat`.

Comment: Can you please share the version of datetimepicker you are using?

Comment: I am the version 1.3.4

Comment: @EduardoAngelim I couldn't find a datepicker of the specified version, wouldn't you mind adding a CDN link to your question?

Comment: I just have the js script file